# In GDB is it possible to give an address relative (in lines) from the start of a function?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

The subject line basically says it all.

If I give the location based on the file and a line number, that value can change if I edit the file. In fact it tends to change quite often and in an inconvenient way if I edit more than a single function during refactoring. However, it's less likely to change if it were (line-)relative to the beginning of a function.

In case it's not possible to give the line offset from the start of a function, then is it perhaps possible to use convenience variables to emulate it? I.e. if I would declare convenience variables that map to the start of a particular function (a list that I would keep updated)?

According to `help break` neither seems to be available, but I thought I'd better ask to be sure.

---

```
(gdb) help break
Set breakpoint at specified line or function.
break [PROBE_MODIFIER] [LOCATION] [thread THREADNUM] [if CONDITION]
PROBE_MODIFIER shall be present if the command is to be placed in a
probe point.  Accepted values are `-probe' (for a generic, automatically
guessed probe type) or `-probe-stap' (for a SystemTap probe).
LOCATION may be a line number, function name, or "*" and an address.
If a line number is specified, break at start of code for that line.
If a function is specified, break at start of code for that function.
If an address is specified, break at that exact address.
With no LOCATION, uses current execution address of the selected
stack frame.  This is useful for breaking on return to a stack frame.

THREADNUM is the number from "info threads".
CONDITION is a boolean expression.

Multiple breakpoints at one place are permitted, and useful if their
conditions are different.

Do "help breakpoints" for info on other commands dealing with breakpoints.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a longstanding request to add this to gdb.  However, it doesn't exist right now.  It's maybe sort of possible with Python, but perhaps not completely, as Python doesn't currently have access to all the breakpoint re-set events (so the breakpoint might work once but not on re-run or library load or some other inferior change).

However, the quoted text shows a nicer way -- use an  probe point.  These are so-called "SystemTap probe points", but in reality they're more like a generic ELF + GCC feature -- they originated from the SystemTap project but don't depend on it.  These let you mark a spot in the source and easily put a breakpoint on it, regardless of other edits to the source.  They are already used on linux distros to mark special spots in the unwinder and longjump runtime routines to make debugging work nicely in the presence of these.

Comment: In addition to probe points, i've also used the 'break function:label' syntax to much the same effect in the past. which might be an option as well.

Comment: @TomTromey: SystemTap is also Linux-specific, right? Whereas ELF, GCC and GDB are not.

Comment: Yeah, SystemTap is Linux-specific.  It might be possible to use sdt.h probes on other systems, though.  I haven't tried but I don't see why not.  The whole devel side of the probes is just a single header file...

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is an old question, but I still could not find a better solution even now in 2017. Here's a Python solution. Maybe it's not the most robust/cleanest one, but it works very well in many practical scenarios:

```
class RelativeFunctionBreakpoint (gdb.Breakpoint):
    def __init__(self, functionName, lineOffset):
        super().__init__(RelativeFunctionBreakpoint.calculate(functionName, lineOffset))

    def calculate(functionName, lineOffset):
        """
        Calculates an absolute breakpoint location (file:linenumber)
        based on functionName and lineOffset
        """
        # get info about the file and line number where the function is defined
        info = gdb.execute("info line "+functionName, to_string=True)
        # extract file name and line number 
        m = re.match(r'Line[^\d]+(\d+)[^"]+"([^"]+)', info)
        if not m:
            raise Exception('Failed to find function %s.' % functionName)
        line = int(m.group(1))+lineOffset #add the lineOffset
        fileName = m.group(2)
        return "%s:%d" % (fileName, line)
```

**USAGE**:

basic:

```
    RelativeFunctionBreakpoint("yourFunctionName", lineOffset=5)
```

custom breakpoint:

```
class YourCustomBreakpoint (RelativeFunctionBreakpoint):
    def __init__(self, funcName, lineOffset, customData):
        super().__init__(funcName, lineOffset)
        self.customData = customData
    def stop(self):
        # do something
        # here you can access self.customData
        return False   #or True if you want the execution to stop
```

**Advantages of the solution**

- relatively fast, because the breakpoint is set only once, before the execution starts
- robust to changes in the source file if they don't affect the function

**Disadvatages**

- Of course, it's not robust to the edits in the function itself
- Not robust to the changes in the output syntax of the *info line funcName* gdb command (probably there is a better way to extract the file name and line number)
- other? you point out