# setting a breakpoint in a specific line inside a function with 'gdb'

Tags: c++, gdb

I am trying to set a breakpoint to the fifth line inside a member function of a class(a class that I created) with 'gdb'.

From [here](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbbreak.html#BCPPFUNC) I understood just how to set a breakpoint at the **begining** of the the function,but I want to set it on a **specific** line inside the function, or a specific **offset** from the begining of this function.

In general is there a way in 'gdb' to set a breakpoint to a line by setting an offset from another breakpoint I already have ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way to set a breakpoint relative to the start of a function such that it will retain its relative position if the source file is modified.  This would sometimes be useful; but it is just a feature that nobody has added to gdb.

It could maybe be emulated from Python, though it couldn't work exactly the way that ordinary breakpoints work, because Python doesn't have access to the breakpoint resetting mechanism inside gdb.

A one-shot solution can be done either as shown in the other answer or from Python.

When I have needed this sort of functionality -- a breakpoint mid-function that is reasonably robust against source changes -- I have used "SDT" static probe points.  These let you name such spots in your source.

Answer (score 22):

You can create a breakpoint at an offset from the current stopped position with `gdb breakpoint +<offset>`.

You can also create a breakpoint on a specific line number using either `gdb break <linenumber>` (for the current source file) or `gdb break <filename>:<linenumber>` (for a file other than the current file).

More details in the [docs](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_29.html).

Comment: additionally you can save your breakpoints to your .gdbinit (in your cwd or your home) and then that will work for the next session.

Answer (score 3):

1. `info fun  <function name>` 
   or fully qualified `info functions  <function name>` 
   gets functions and their source files
2. `list <function name>`

> Print lines centered around the beginning of function function.

Will list all function's source code, with some code below.

3. Choose line you want
4. `break <filename:linenum>`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can automate it with python scripts for GDB:

```
class RelativeFunctionBreakpoint (gdb.Breakpoint):
    def __init__(self, functionName, lineOffset):
        super().__init__(RelativeFunctionBreakpoint.calculate(functionName, lineOffset))

    def calculate(functionName, lineOffset):
        """
        Calculates an absolute breakpoint location (file:linenumber)
        based on functionName and lineOffset
        """
        # get info about the file and line number where the function is defined
        info = gdb.execute("info line "+functionName, to_string=True)
        # extract file name and line number 
        m = re.match(r'Line[^\d]+(\d+)[^"]+"([^"]+)', info)
        if not m:
            raise Exception('Failed to find function %s.' % functionName)
        line = int(m.group(1))+lineOffset #add the lineOffset
        fileName = m.group(2)
        return "%s:%d" % (fileName, line)
```

**Basic usage:**

```
RelativeFunctionBreakpoint("yourFunctionName", lineOffset=5)
```

You can also write a custom breakpoint. See more here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46737659/5787022

Using python to script GDB

- Official documentation:
  https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html
- Some exapmles: http://tromey.com/blog/?p=548